# Knockout custom binding handlers - multiple arguments and function callbacks best practice?

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-validate

I recently created a binding handler to incorporate the JQuery Validation plugin into a form using the data-bind syntax. I found myself needing to supply more than one piece of info to the handler. I needed to supply a flag to enforce validation and a callback to fire once validation passed.

Questions:

1. What is the best practice for supplying multiple args? I just relied on the object notation syntax, but could also supply another binding and check that binding via the "allBindings" param passed to the handler...
2. What is the best practice for supplying a callback function to a handler?

Below is the js code defining the handler and the html code to apply the handler:

```
     <form id="step1" 
        data-bind="jqValidation:{enforce: true, 
                                 submitHandler: doSomethingInVM}">
           <fieldset data-bind="with:searchRequest">
            //fields
           </fieldset>
           <button type="submit">submit</button>
     </form>
```

---

```
     ko.bindingHandlers.jqValidation = {

        update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
            var accessor = valueAccessor();
            //need unwrapobservable??
            if (accessor.enforce) {
                $(element).find(':submit').removeClass('cancel');
                $(element).validate({
                    submitHandler: function () {
                        if ($.isFunction(accessor.submitHandler))
                            accessor.submitHandler();
                    }
                });
            } else
                $(element).find(':submit').addClass('cancel');
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 8):

Your approach here follows the pattern used by KO itself so I think it is perfectly valid. Granted you could also use the allBindingsAccessor. The way I have interpreted the usage of this method is to

1. Share properties between multiple bindings, for example a bubbleEvent binding could be used to indicate to any other binding that deals with events not to bubble them.
2. To allow complex binding handlers to be aware of other bindings and adjust their behavior.

The best practice for passing handlers is to have them as named members on your view model rather than inline on the binding.

Comment: Thanks, that was my thinking on the allBindingsAccessor method too. So, in my case, would you not pass the handler in the data-bind attribute?

Comment: I would pass it as part of the object referencing back to your VM exactly as you have done. You could also write the handler out inline which is ugly and considered bad practice.

Comment: Ah, yes I agree, I'm guilty of a few of those on my first ko project :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer both of your questions, a strongly recommended practice when using knockoutjs and the MVVM pattern is to encapsulate properties and methods pertinent to your objects in their respective view models.

That said, it works very well to have any properties (arguments if you will) and callback methods that will be responsible for updating your view model (or triggering updates to other objects due to changes in your view model) to reside on the view model itself.

Then inside your custom binding handler you can simply reference any properties you need directly from your view model, as well as call any callback functions residing on the view model.

Encapsulating members and behaviors in this manner makes it very straightforward to unit test each view model as well.